# C++: Find method

Tags: c++

so if i were to enter patricia(don't worry im converting it toupper) that string would be loaded into my vector.
My question is about the find functions. i am counting down characters correct? so if i were to enter patricia and j would be on ABBOT, PATRICIA the value in comma would be 5. Ok im good so far, but what happens in my found variable?

```
bool NameSearch::findFirstNames(vector<string> &vsFirst, string name)
{ 

int j = 0;
bool bName = false;
vsFirst.clear();

while(j < total)
{  
    int comma;
    comma = names[j].find(',');

            //Confused here
    int found = names[j].find(name, comma);

    if(found > -1)  
    {
        vsFirst.push_back(names[j]);
        bName = true;
    }

        j++;
} 

return bName;
}
```

Comment: im sorry names is the array of the all 1000 names. total is just 1000.

Comment: the while loop is going through each name in the text file.

Comment: What **exactly** is `names`?  Is it an array of `std::string`?

Comment: correct. a string array.

Comment: 7 for Patricia, that is the index in the string where the searched string starts. Since it found it `(index!=npos)` it adds the whole string to the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two other answers, that point out what is wrong with this code, but I feel like none of them explains to you, what the author was doing, and that's the explanation you want. :)

Let's look at the following snippet first.

```
int comma;
comma = names[j].find(',');
```

As pointed out, it should be rewritten as:

```
size_t comma;
comma = names[j].find(',');
```

There are 4 overloads of the `find` method in the `std::string`
The code above uses this one:

```
size_t find (char c, size_t pos = 0) const;
```

It returns the index, at which the character passed as the first argument (in your case it's `','`) appears in the string or `std::string::npos` if that character isn't found. Apparently the author is sure the `','` character must be present in the string `names[j]` and doesn't check the result.

In the line:

```
int found = names[j].find(name, comma);
```

which again should be rewritten as:

```
size_t found = names[j].find(name, comma);
```

the following overload of the `find` method is used:

```
size_t find (const string& str, size_t pos = 0) const;
```

This one searches the string `names[j]` for the first occurrence of the string passed as the first argument (in your case `name`) and returns the index at which the match starts if there is a match or `std::string::npos` otherwise.

As you can see, both mentioned overloads of the `find` method have a second parameter with default value of `0`. This second parameter allows a user to specify, at what index to start the search in the searched string (in your case `names[j]`)

The call:

```
comma = names[j].find(',');
```

is equivalent to the call:

```
comma = names[j].find(',', 0);
```

and it means: look for the character `','` int the string `names[j]` starting from the beginning and return the index of the first occurrence of that character or `std::string::npos`, if there is no such character in that string.

The call:

```
size_t found = names[j].find(name, comma);
```

means: look for the substring equal to `name` in the string `names[j]`, but start from the position where the comma was found and return the index of the first occurrence of that substring or `std::string::npos` if there is no such substring in that string, after the comma.

Maybe `comma_position` instead of `comma` would have been a better name for the variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `if (found > -1)` test probably works on your platform but is technically dubious.

The return type of `std::string::find()` is `std::string::size_type`, and if the substring you're searching is not found, the returned value is `std::string::npos` (on the other hand, if the substring is found, the returned value is the character index of its first occurrence).

Now the `std::string::npos` value happens to be the greatest possible value of type `std::string::size_type`, and if that is `unsigned int` on your implementation, that means the comparison with the *signed* int `-1` will yield `true`.

However, no assumptions can be made in general on the type of `std::string::size_type` Thus, I suggest to rewrite the test as:

```
if (found != std::string::npos)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is misleading code.  `std::string::find()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

```
int comma;
comma = names[j].find(',');
```

This is misleading code.  When `std::string::find()` fails, it returns `std::string::npos`, not `-1`.  In your environment, it's equivalent to `-1` by coincidence.

```
if(found > -1)
```

The if statement is effectively trying to check "*if a result was found*" by making sure it isn't `std::string::npos`.

Comment: Thanks! what is that strange number it assigns to string::npos? 4294967295

Comment: and to found for that matter. now that i changed it to a size_t

Comment: @user1979708 it's a number that's guaranteed not to be a valid string index.  That's all that's important, but in your particular case it happens to be 2^32-1